# Android root view onClickListener is always triggered

Tags: android, view, click, onclicklistener

I have a simple problem with views in Android. I have two view rootView and containerView, containerView is contained in rootView, but I don't understand why when I click on containerView rootView is triggered.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    rootView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("esx","ROOT VIEW ID: "+v.getId());
        }
    });

    LinearLayout containerView = new LinearLayout(this);
    containerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100));
    containerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    rootView.addView(containerView);

    setContentView(rootView);
}}
```

I want that when I click containerView, nothing happens. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `containerView.setClickable(true)`

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` provides a `View` argument. Just compare it and see if it's the `rootView`. If that doesn't work, try to see if that **ISN'T** the `containerView` (you'll need to declare it before adding the listener.