# How to detect click on empty space?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, touch

I'm trying to create an activity that lets me place and move `imageviews` around. To create new `imageviews` I wanted to tap on an empty space. However, I can't see how I can implement that. There isn't a specific object I can set an `OnClickListener` to. Unless then I'd set the root layout as to the `OnClickListener` but then how am I supposed to check that it's empty space?

In short, how do I detect when the user touches an empty space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a listener on a view that contains your images (holder). If it's rootView - that's completely fine.
The thing is that onClick will work on direct interaction with that view, which basically means if you click on other views *within* your holder (children/item overlapping holder), nothing should happen.

You might need to set your image views clickable by calling imageView.setClickable(true) and you will not get rootView's false click. Related: [Android root view onClickListener is always triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783331/android-root-view-onclicklistener-is-always-triggered)

**So to sum up:** you should not check empty space by yourself, system does it for you

Comment: Thanks! but I have one question. When I touch an `imageview` to drag it will also trigger the root layout's `OnClickListener` so how do I check I didn't click on an `imageview`? If iI doesn't check, it will create a new `imageview` when I try to drag an already present `imageview`.

Comment: Updated the answer